# Some of the keys on my laptop don't work. What can I do?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, keyboard

Some of the keys that don't work include the: Caps Lock key (light doesn't turn on), X, C, Left Control key, M.

Can anyone explain if there is a software issue that could cause this? I don't have anything fancy installed on my Windows 7 machine. Just a regular install.

I'm using a Toshiba A665.

There haven't been any drops, or spills or **any damage** whatsoever done to the machine. I'm sure it's a software issue. What would cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your comfortability with linux, you could simply boot into a Live CD of any linux distribution (dead simple to do and doesn't install the OS or anything). If your keys work in there, then yes it's software. If they don't work in the LiveCD, then it must be hardware.

Comment: What's odd is that if I press the Shift key 5 times, I get the Sticky Keys prompt. But when holding the shift key to enter my password it's as if the shift isn't holding.

Comment: Now I **KNOW** it's software. I just pressed WindowsKey + X to access the mobility center to dim the screen and the keys started working. All of the them. God damn this frikkin Toshiba crap software. I'm afraid to uninstall something and have it break.

Comment: Hmmmm, just to make sure you're using US standard keyboard language? Also I've heard some bad things about Satellite laptops when it comes to keyboard issues. Can you restore to a recent restore point?

Comment: US standard keyboard language, assuming you're in the US.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot more like a hardware problem to me.  Fortunately, laptop keyboards these days are often replaceable without too much fuss (or money).  Check here:
http://shop.ebay.com/?_from=R40&_trksid=p5197.m570.l1313&_nkw=Toshiba+A665+keyboard&_sacat=See-All-Categories